# Can't launch Celery worker within a Django project

Tags: python, django, task, celery, message-queue

Recently, I started using Celery 4.0.2 with Django 1.9.10 to run some periodic tasks. Basically, I run into two problems even though I followed the steps mentioned in the official documentation:

- Celery app is not discovering the tasks that are included in every app directory
- When I manually add the tasks to the Celery App and try to run the worker, I get this error:

  RuntimeError: Model class core.models.Modl doesn't declare an      explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

This is how I create the Celery App:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from .scraper import scraper_example

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'conf')
app = Celery('celery_power',
         broker=settings.CELERY_BROCKER_URL,
         backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND,
         include=['apps.core.tasks'])
# app.autodiscover_tasks() in case I don't include the tasks module, 
# never worked by the way
```

For my tasks.py that I created in the core app directory, I simply import a few models and used them to insert some data, something like this:

```
from .models import Modl
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def deal_with_modl():
    m = Modl(name="model")
    m.save()
```

Comment: What command are you using to start the worker, and what's your directory structure? Also, you put the celery import in `__init__.py`? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: to launch the worker I use: celery -A celery_power worker --loglevel=info, as for the project structure and at the root level, I have a directory celery_power that contains the celery app configuration and an "apps" directory that contains all the apps, among them "core" that includes the tasks.py file

Comment: Is the directory that the celery app is in called `celery_power`? If not, you should swap those out so the command is `celery -A some_directory worker --loglevel=info`

Comment: There actually a directory called celery_power

Comment: I haven't used the shared_task decorator so I had to do some reading, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for and could be causing the issues. Shared task "lets you create tasks without having any concrete app instance" - you should try adding `from celery_power.a_file import app` and replace `@shared_task` with `@app.task`. Also, did you have settings referenced in `autodiscover_tasks`: `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`?

Comment: How are you invoking the tasks? Have you already looked at this page: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-naming-relative-imports

Comment: @JensAstrup the shared_task decorator is actually good whenver you use incorporate tasks in your Django apps. This means that you tasks can be used by any Celery App and not by a specific app exclusively. I don't think that decorator is causing any harm to the worker.

Comment: @JeanJung To invoke my worker, I use this command: 
celery -A celery_power worker --loglevel=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue has to do with the way I structured my django project. Essentially, the celery app was not loading when django starts. By removing the celery_power directory (I simply used a single file celery_app.py that sits at the root level of the project) and following the structure below, celery app was able to autodiscover all my tasks and I was able to launch my workers with no issues:

[image: Project Structure]